# Regular expressions which accept Apostrophes in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a validation form in PHP which only accepts.

- Lower-case letters
- Upper-case letters
- Numbers
- Spaces between words
- Punctuation symbols ':,.!().?"

So far I have tried `'#^[a-zA-Z0-9" *":,.!-().?";\']+$#i'`
Using the `if (preg_match()){`
But this only passes letters, numbers & full stops

I want it to accept production descriptions like this "The future of home entertainment!" & "Play CD's"

I'm fairly new to regular expressions so I'm not sure if I'm missing any 
characters or it is something to do with the way I am coding it in PHP.

Comment: are accented letters allowed or letters from an other alphabet, same with digits?

Comment: The expression you have matches all of the symbols you have defined, but I'm not sure if regex validation is really necessary. What if a description has something like '10% off' or 'Play Movies + Games'? Could you explain your use case further?

Comment: Just plan English text and it is just like a very basic description of a product I am trying to pass from a CSV file to my Database but yeah like you stated '10% off' or 'Play Movies + Games' would probably be in there as well if the user inputs that kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
$regex = '#^[a-zA-Z0-9" *:,.!().?";\'-]+$#i' ;

$list = ["The future of home entertainment!","Play CD's"];
foreach ($list as $sentence) {
    var_dump(preg_match($regex, $sentence));
}
```

Always put dash (-) at the end in [] if you want to match dash also.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work with it being put into a while loop to pass data from a CSV file to a MYSQL database.

Comment: @user3047041 Im not sure what you mean. This tests if the string only contains acceptable characters. Nothing more or less.

Comment: I'm using a while loop to take data out of an excel file and then be validated by regular expressions to and once passed be inserted into the database using an If Else statement.

Comment: @user3047041 And preg_match does return 1 if it only contains chars in the regex, 0 if they don't. If you have a question about the csv or sql insert you should probably open a new question.If you have any other questions about the regex not working on a string please ask.